# script runs twice in raspbian

Tags: linux, bash, rc

I am new to Raspberry Pi and I wanted to run a program automatically after the Pi bootsup. I script works fine when I tried to run `./myscript.sh`. As it is need to run everytime the Pi powered-up, I have mentioned the script path in `/etc/rc.local` as `/home/pi/myscript.sh` above `exit 0`.

Once I reboot the Pi, I could see the log messages from my script and so on, but when I tried to see the process Id I found two process for the application I start using the script.

```
root     607    1    11:30  ?     00:00:00  /bin/sh -e /etc/rc.local start
root     615    607  11:30  ?     00:00:00  /bin/bash /home/pi/myscript.sh
root     684    615  11:30  ?     00:00:00  sudo ./rte -bf runappl.xml
root     689    684  11:30  ?     00:00:00  ./rte -bf runappl.xml
```

and myscript.sh will look like

```
#!/bin/bash
echo " Configuring eth0 multicast ... "
sudo ifconfig eth0 multicast
sudo route add -net 224.0.0.0 netmask 240.0.0.0 dev eth0

export rte_bin_dir="../home/pi/rte/bin/"
if [ -d "$rte_bin_dir" ]; then
  cd "./$rte_bin_dir"
  sudo ./rte -bf runappl.xml
else
  echo "unable to locate ${rte_bin_dir}"
  exit 1
fi
```

Is this the correct result expected or am I assuming something wrong?

Is there a way to run the script automatically after I see the desktop(main screen)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is normal, as you are sudoing your command.
One process (684) is used for the switch user part (sudo here), the other one (689) for the program itself.

So it's ok, your program is not running twice.